# Prove the sequence has no limit

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I want to prove the sequence $a_n = (-1)^n + 1/n$ has no limit for $n\to +\infty$.

Here is my attempts.

By the definition, let's suppose $a_n$ has a limit, and call it $\ell$. Since for $n\to +\infty$ we have $(-1)^n + 1/n$ = \pm 1$ we intuitively know there is no limit. But let's suppose there is.

Let's say $\ell = 1$ and $n$ is even. Then

$$|(-1)^n + 1/n -\ell | < \epsilon \implies |1 + 1/n - 1| < \epsilon$$

This means $1/n < \epsilon$. For this case it seems like the sequence has limit though.

But if I choose $\ell = 1$ and $n$ odd, then I get

$$|-1 + 1/n - 1| < \epsilon \implies |1/n - 2| < \epsilon$$

Now here we can see that as $n\to +\infty$, $1/n - 2 \to -2$ and hence $|-2| = 2 < \epsilon$ means $\epsilon > 2$, which contradicts the limit definition "$\forall \epsilon$".

I don't know if this is correct or not, but I am wondering why in the first choice I get something that appears all good. Perhaps it's because the limit is indeed $\ell = 1$ when $n$ goes to infinity "in an even way"...?

But this would prove the limit exists.

If I do the same thing for $\ell = -1$ and $n$ odd, I too get the limit exists.

How to interpret the two existences? Maybe I shall invoke the theorem for which if the limit exists then it should be unique?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Consider the sub-sequences given by $~\{a_1, a_3, a_5,\cdots\}~$ and $~\{a_2, a_4, a_6, \cdots\}.$  Each sub-sequence is convergent, and the two sub-sequences converge to two different values.  Therefore, the overall sequence can not be convergent.

Comment: @user2661923 May I ask you more details in merit? I thought of what you told me, but say I have the convergent sequence $\frac{1}{2^n}$. Then two subsequences of this one are $\frac{1}{4^n}$ and $\frac{1}{8^n}$, but they do converge to different limits, hence $\frac{1}{2^n}$ shouldn't have a limit... But it does.

Comment: In the 2nd example, both of the sub-sequences converge to $~0.$

Comment: @user2661923 Right! I was thinking about the series...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complement John Hughes' (+1) answer and the comments, we can apply the reverse triangle inequality to arbitrary consecutive terms, deducing
\begin{align*}
  |a_{n+1} - a_{n}|
  &= \left\lvert(-1)^{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} - (-1)^{n} - \frac{1}{n}\right\rvert \\
  &= \left\lvert2(-1)^{n+1} - \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right\rvert \\
  &\geq 2 - \frac{1}{n(n+1)} \\
  &\geq 3/2
\end{align*}
for all $n \geq 1$.

If we know about Cauchy sequences and the fact that a convergent sequence is Cauchy, we can deduce that our sequence is not Cauchy, therefore not convergent.

Alternatively, fix an arbitrary real number $L$ as prospective limit and pick an arbitrary positive $\varepsilon < 3/4$. If $(a_{n}) \to L$, then for sufficiently large $n$ we have $|a_{n} - L| < \varepsilon < 3/4$. The triangle inequality implies
$$
|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| \leq |(a_{n+1} - L) - (a_{n} - L)|
\leq |a_{n+1} - L| + |a_{n} - L|
< 3/4 + 3/4 = 3/2.
$$
Contrapositively, since "$|a_{n+1} - a_{n}| < 3/2$" is false for all $n \geq 1$, the hypothesis $(a_{n}) \to L$ is false. Since $L$ was an arbitrary real number, $(a_{n})$ has no limit.

Comment: Personally I don't _recommend_ writing the proof this way (using subsequences seems more clear), but it may be conceptually reassuring to know a proof _can_ be written this way.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will carefully look at this in a while. I have a question: you said "it's not Cauchy therefore not convergent". I know that any sequence which is a Cauchy sequence is convergent. So we can then sauy that if a sequence is not Cauchy therefore is not convergent? This would mean that there is an "if only if" in the middle, not just a "if then". Right?

Comment: "Yes, but....": The "Cauchy implies convergent" property has fine print related to "completeness" in some form, and is non-trivial to prove for real sequences. By contrast, "convergent implies Cauchy" is generally true (for "sequences in metric spaces"), and easily-established directly from the definitions and the triangle inequality. Here, that is, we only need the easy implication.

Answer (score 3):

You've shown, perhaps, that neither $\ell = 1$ nor $\ell = -1$ (by symmetry) can be the limit. But could the sequence have a limit of $11.25$? You haven't shown that *that* is impossible. Nor have you addressed any of the tons of other possible limits. So you're not done.

Here's a suggestion: show that if the sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ has a limit $L$, then any (infinite) subsequence *also* has the limit $L$.

Now see whether you can apply that idea to this problem.